# Combinatorics question about cube with vertices marked as + or - 1 and faces marked with the product of 4 vertices

Tags: combinatorics

This question is from a practice workbook for a college entrance exam.

Let each corner of a cube is represented by +1 or -1 arbitrarily and on each of the six faces of the cube we write the product of numbers written at four corners of that face. Let $s_1, s_2, s_3,...,s_8$ be the numbers written on the corners and $p_1,p_2,...,p_6$ be the product of numbers written on the faces. Then the total number of ways to make the solution of the equation- $$\Sigma_{i=1}^8s_i + \Sigma_{i=1}^6p_i = 0 $$

So my first thought was to work case by case. $\Sigma_{i=1}^8s_i$ can take values of {-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8} and $\Sigma_{i=1}^6p_i$ can take values {-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6} even if we ignore possible configurations and just give each $p_i$ a value equal to -1 or 1.
Now clearly $\Sigma_{i=1}^8s_i = -8,8$ will not give any solutions to the equation.

For the case where $\Sigma_{i=1}^8s_i = 6$. There are 7, +1 vertices and 1, -1 vertex. This will hence give $\Sigma_{i=1}^6p_i = 0$ Because that single (-1) vertex will make three products -1.

For the case where $\Sigma_{i=1}^8s_i = 4$. There are 2, (-1)vertices and three ways to place them. If you take body diagonals, the product will be -6, if you take face diagonals, the sum of products will be -2 and for adjacent vertices the sum of products will be +2.
Now while this approach of taking cases does work and will get the answer, it is rather long(the $\Sigma_{i=1}^8s_i = 2$ case will have way more possibilities) and also leaves plenty of scope to go wrong or miscount. So I was looking for maybe an organized way to check these cases or an alternate method entirely which utilizes maybe some different intuition.

Also I'm unsure what to tag this question under, so if someone would comment some tags or edit this post to include useful tags, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't quite understand why that particular approach was chosen and why it works. What made you think about switching the 1s for 0 and -1s for 1 and replacing multiplication by addition. Should I ask this in a comment in this linked question and delete this question?

Comment: Operational equivalence.

Comment: I'm in high school and I don't think we've ever touched on that topic before. Maybe you could provide a link to some reading on this and how to know when to use it?